# Update my application without running the code again

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple Python GUI application using Tkinter
I would like to create a button that updates new code edits without pressing: Run Code Again, so technically the button will run the code using the new update without closing the GUI window;
let's say this is my simple original code:

## The code does the sum operation: X + Y

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Solver Math")

txt_Z = StringVar()

def Solve():

    X = float(e_X.get()) 
    Y = float(e_Y.get())
    Z = X + Y
    txt_Z.set(str(Z))
    txt_Z.set("{0:.3f}".format(Z))

l_X = Label(root, text="Enter X",width=20, anchor="w").grid(row=0,column=0)
e_X = Entry(root, width=25)
e_X.grid(row=0,column=1)

l_Y = Label(root, text="Enter Y",width=20, anchor="w").grid(row=1,column=0)
e_Y = Entry(root, width=25)
e_Y.grid(row=1,column=1)

l_Z_text = Label(root,text="The Value of Z is", width=30, anchor="w").grid(row=3,column=0)
l_Z_num = Label(root,textvariable=txt_Z).grid(row=3,column=1)

b_Solve = Button(root, text="Solve", command=lambda: Solve(), width=10)
b_Solve.grid(row=2,column=0)

root.geometry("300x300")
root.mainloop()
```

Now I want the code to do the operation:

```
    Z = X - Y
```

How can I create a refresh or update button that implement this change: (Z = X - Y) in the code without closing the application window and running again

My code contains lot of math equations that need to be coded one by one and each equation contains many variables so ***I want to save time*** not inputting the variables (like x and y) values whenever I add to my code new math equation

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: would be better if you provide both add and subtract functions, and use the button as a boolean for toggling which one gets called.

Comment: if your goal is to add/change functionality until you complete your code then re-running the code is much easier than making the window behave like that, there are very few cases in which this type of behavior would be necessary so the question is: why do you think you need this?

Comment: AntiMatterDynamite Thank you for your answer. My code contains lot of math equations that need to be coded one by one and each equation contains many variables so I want to save time not inputting the variables (like x and y) values whenever I add to my code new math equation.

Comment: @YuvaJo Implement [Radiobutton Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm) and react on which option is selected.

Comment: create another button which runs code function with `Z = X - Y`. OR use `Radiobutton` to select what to calculate. You could eventually try to use `eval("X-Y")` to use `X-Y` as string from `Entry`.

Comment: maybe you should save `x`, `y` in file and read it when you run script again.